# Spring controller not working when the last PathVariable in RequestMapping has only

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to map a request to Spring controller but it is not working as expected

I get 404 error when I am trying /simple/test/something/.....
and my mapping is as follows `@RequestMapping(path="/simple/test/{string1}/{string2}")`

Below is my code

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/search/test/{string1}/{string2}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public SearchResult search( @PathVariable String string1, @PathVariable Optional string2) {
    if (!query.isPresent()) {
        return service.getLastQueries(string1, string2);
    }
}
```

when the {string2} contains / or only .... then I am getting 404 error.
For example {string2} is ....... or some/thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.

But in my case the second string should be optional sometimes. I changed the second string to "RequestParam" so that the new url would be something like this `/simple/test?q=something`

new requestmapping would be `@RequestMapping(path="/simple/test/{string1}")`

so the solution code is

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/search/test/{string1}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public SearchResult search( @PathVariable String string1, @RequestParam Optional<String> string2) {
    if (!string2.isPresent()) {
        return service.getLastQueries(string1, string2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to make input parameter as `Optional`, you should also set `required=false` in `@PathVariable` annotation.

```
@PathVariable(required=false) Optional<String> string2
```

Answer (score 0):

As @DDovzhenko pointed out u can not just declare an Optional type. Actually you should not do that at all, because u are expecting a String and should stick to that. In combination with the

```
required=false
```

attribute of the @PathVariable it should work fine:

```
@PathVariable(required=false) String urVariable
```